# How do I properly serialize an object in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, serialization

I am trying to serialize certain custom data types. For the simpler ones (like UUID) the approach described in [Kotlin Serialization](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/serialization.html) worked great. However I am running into some issues with more complex types. Here is my code:

object class:

```
@Serializable(with = PairSerializer::class) //error here
private val equipment = mutableListOf<Pair<ItemSlot, ItemStack>>()
```

serializer class:

```
class PairSerializer() : KSerializer<Pair<EnumWrappers.ItemSlot, ItemStack>> {
    override val descriptor: SerialDescriptor = buildClassSerialDescriptor("PairEnumISSerializer") {
    }

    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: Pair<EnumWrappers.ItemSlot, ItemStack>) {
    //implementation
    }

    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): Pair<EnumWrappers.ItemSlot, ItemStack> {
    //implementation
    }
}
```

here is the error I am getting:

`Serializer has not been found for type 'Pair<EnumWrappers.ItemSlot, ItemStack>'. To use context serializer as fallback, explicitly annotate type or property with @Contextual`

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f35gJ.jpg)

I can't exactly put

`@Serializer(forClass = Pair<EnumWrappers.ItemSlot, ItemStack>::class)`

above the serializer class because that shows error:
"Only classes are allowed on the left hand side of a class literal"
and I haven't been able to find any answers online so far.

- I tried putting @Serializable above the value that needs to be serialized but that doesn't work.
- I tried Serializing each type on It's own, but that didn't work.
- I tried putting @Serializer above the serializer class as I did with the serializer for UUID class, but that doesn't work due to aforementioned error.
- I tried doing away with mutable list of pairs and using a map. Wrote a new serializer for "ItemStack", and I got basically the same error, just with "ItemStack" instead of the previous one:

`Serializer has not been found for type 'ItemStack'. To use context serializer as fallback,  explicitly annotate type or property with @Contextual`

Comment: [Does this answer your question perhaps?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75461166/5133585)

Comment: @Sweeper unfortunately, it doesn't work. Still the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: After some trial and error, this is what finally worked:

```
@Serializable(with = PairSerializer::class)
private val equipment = hashMapOf<ItemSlot,@Serializable(with = ItemStackSerializer::class) ItemStack>()
```

Essentially, both the list/map need their own serializer as does the custom data type itself